# Multiple yields in sequence comprehension?

Tags: scala, yield, list-comprehension

I'm trying to learn Scala and tried to write a sequence comprehension that extracts unigrams, bigrams and trigrams from a sequence. E.g., [1,2,3,4] should be transformed to (not Scala syntax)

```
[1; _,1; _,_,1; 2; 1,2; _,1,2; 3; 2,3; 1,2,3; 4; 3,4; 2,3,4]
```

In Scala 2.8, I tried the following:

```
def trigrams(tokens : Seq[T]) = {
  var t1 : Option[T] = None
  var t2 : Option[T] = None
  for (t3 <- tokens) {
    yield t3
    yield (t2,t3)
    yield (t1,t2,Some(t3))
    t1 = t2
    t2 = t3
  }
}
```

But this doesn't compile as, [apparently](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/111), only one `yield` is allowed in a `for`-comprehension (no block statements either). Is there any other elegant way to get the same behavior, with only one pass over the data?

Comment: Not a scala programmer, but it looks like you're returning 1-tuple, 2-tuple, and 3-tuple, none of which have the same data type. So it probably isn't type-checking. Each element should have the same data type, such as a 3-tuple in this case. In F#/OCaml, you'd wrap up your different return types in a union as such, `let trigram = One of 'a | Two of 'a * 'a | Three of 'a * 'a * 'a`, then you can `yield One(t3); yield Two(t2, t3); yield Three(t1, t2, t3)`, where the return type is `seq<trigram<Option<'a>>>`.

Comment: It does type check if I declare the result as Seq[Any], or if I use classes `Unigram`, `Bigram` and `Trigram`, derived from `Ngram`, instead of tuples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't have multiple yields in a for loop because for loops are syntactic sugar for the map (or flatMap) operations:

```
for (i <- collection) yield( func(i) )
```

translates into

```
collection map {i => func(i)}
```

Without a yield at all

```
for (i <- collection) func(i)
```

translates into

```
collection foreach {i => func(i)}
```

So the entire body of the `for` loop is turned into a single closure, and the presence of the `yield` keyword determines whether the function called on the collection is `map` or `foreach` (or `flatMap`). Because of this translation, the following are forbidden:

1. Using imperative statements next to a `yield` to determine what will be yielded.
2. Using multiple yields

(Not to mention that your proposed verison will return a `List[Any]` because the tuples and the 1-gram are all of different types. You probably want to get a `List[List[Int]]` instead)

Try the following instead (which put the n-grams in the order they appear):

```
val basis = List(1,2,3,4)
val slidingIterators = 1 to 4 map (basis sliding _)

for {onegram <- basis
     ngram <- slidingIterators if ngram.hasNext}
     yield (ngram.next)
```

or

```
val basis = List(1,2,3,4)
val slidingIterators = 1 to 4 map (basis sliding _)
val first=slidingIterators head
val buf=new ListBuffer[List[Int]]

while (first.hasNext)
   for (i <- slidingIterators)
      if (i.hasNext)
         buf += i.next
```

If you prefer the n-grams to be in length order, try:

```
val basis = List(1,2,3,4)
1 to 4 flatMap { basis sliding _ toList }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> val basis = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
basis: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> val nGrams = (basis sliding 1).toList ::: (basis sliding 2).toList ::: (basis sliding 3).toList
nGrams: List[List[Int]] = ...

scala> nGrams foreach (println _)
List(1)
List(2)
List(3)
List(4)
List(1, 2)
List(2, 3)
List(3, 4)
List(1, 2, 3)
List(2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: This is going to be a little slow on account of the `:::` operator.

Comment: The concatenation doesn't have to happen. I just wanted to illustrate that `sliding n` does the essential work of extracting `n`-grams. And whether it's really "slow" depends on other parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I should have given this more thought.

```
def trigrams(tokens : Seq[T]) : Seq[(Option[T],Option[T],T)] = {
  var t1 : Option[T] = None
  var t2 : Option[T] = None
  for (t3 <- tokens)
    yield {
      val tri = (t1,t2,t3)
      t1 = t2
      t2 = Some(t3)
      tri
    }
}
```

Then extract the unigrams and bigrams from the trigrams. But can anyone explain to me why 'multi-yields' are not permitted, and if there's any other way to achieve their effect?

Comment: to achieve their effect, try to add another nested level of iteration, as in my first proposed solution to your problem.

Comment: Multiple yields (if you see them as exit points which they aren’t) would turn the simple closure into a coroutine which is one reason they are not so easy to deal with. There are some solutions with the continuations plugin, however.

Answer (score 1):

```
val basis = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
val nGrams = basis.map(x => (x)) ::: (for (a <- basis; b <- basis) yield (a, b)) ::: (for (a <- basis; b <- basis; c <- basis) yield (a, b, c))
nGrams: List[Any] = ...
nGrams foreach (println(_))
1
2
3
4
(1,1)
(1,2)
(1,3)
(1,4)
(2,1)
(2,2)
(2,3)
(2,4)
(3,1)
(3,2)
(3,3)
(3,4)
(4,1)
(4,2)
(4,3)
(4,4)
(1,1,1)
(1,1,2)
(1,1,3)
(1,1,4)
(1,2,1)
(1,2,2)
(1,2,3)
(1,2,4)
(1,3,1)
(1,3,2)
(1,3,3)
(1,3,4)
(1,4,1)
(1,4,2)
(1,4,3)
(1,4,4)
(2,1,1)
(2,1,2)
(2,1,3)
(2,1,4)
(2,2,1)
(2,2,2)
(2,2,3)
(2,2,4)
(2,3,1)
(2,3,2)
(2,3,3)
(2,3,4)
(2,4,1)
(2,4,2)
(2,4,3)
(2,4,4)
(3,1,1)
(3,1,2)
(3,1,3)
(3,1,4)
(3,2,1)
(3,2,2)
(3,2,3)
(3,2,4)
(3,3,1)
(3,3,2)
(3,3,3)
(3,3,4)
(3,4,1)
(3,4,2)
(3,4,3)
(3,4,4)
(4,1,1)
(4,1,2)
(4,1,3)
(4,1,4)
(4,2,1)
(4,2,2)
(4,2,3)
(4,2,4)
(4,3,1)
(4,3,2)
(4,3,3)
(4,3,4)
(4,4,1)
(4,4,2)
(4,4,3)
(4,4,4)
```

Comment: No, this gives a list of (what I think are called) multiset combinations. I'm looking for n-grams, substrings. It also passes over `basis` three times. What is `:::`, by the way?

Comment: `basis` is iterated six times. `:::` is `List` concatenation.

Comment: Performance wasn't a part of the question, was it? `:::` O(n) where n is the length of its RHS argument.

Comment: `:::` is O(n) where n is the length of its LHS argument.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a functional version without assignments:

```
def trigrams[T](tokens : Seq[T]) = {
  val s1 = tokens.map { Some(_) }
  val s2 = None +: s1
  val s3 = None +: s2
  s1 zip s2 zip s3 map {
    case ((t1, t2), t3) => (List(t1), List(t1, t2), List(t1, t2, t3))
  }
}
```